# xfce4 close_window_key on desktop background offers to log out

Tags: xfce, xfwm4

For xfce4 I have defined a keyboard shortcut for `close_window_key`. When I apply it to the desktop background, i.e. without window focus, I am offered the logout dialog as if `xfce4-session-logout` was called.

I would like to redefine the behavior, for example to initiate logout+shutdown after a short grace period. (Like from the panel's Shutdown button.)

Question: is it possible to redefine the `close_window_key` behavior in the context of the desktop background?

EDIT: Hmm, will start digging if nobody knows by heart: https://github.com/xfce-mirror/xfwm4/blob/db7e5e5722635c69d66ed2e58ec3a15f7b04efa8/src/events.c#L475

Comment: :-) I followed the code a bit further to see what the session-manager has to offer, but it seems to be similarly hardcoded. Your solution, maybe combined with a zenity script, is probably what I'll do.